# Generate getter/setter, hashcode/equals, toString in one template in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

It is possible to generate getter/setter, hashcode/equals, toString in one click? Right now I have to choose each one separetely.

Comment: You can follow and vote this request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-179152

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Each of the generators has a distinct UI where you need to specify the details of the methods you need, so it wouldn't save any significant effort if the generators were combined.