# Intellij Plugin to generate getter/setter, hashcode/equals, toString

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, generated-code

Hi is there any plugin for IntelliJ, which can generate getter/setter, hashcode/equals, toString in one click?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate getter/setter, hashcode/equals, toString in one template in Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490265/generate-getter-setter-hashcode-equals-tostring-in-one-template-in-intellij)

Comment: I use CMD+N (on mac) for showing generate menu where i can choose what to generate. See in Preferences and search for short cuts if this is is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a plugin Generatable (Kirill Korgov): "Generate All: getters, equals and hashCode, toString, Constructor, Builder"

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want one click?

You have the keybinding `alt+insert` and 'Getter/Setters' in the popup menu.

But, if you want an automatic setters and getters generation, you have the `@data` annotation on bean class from [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data).

Comment: In some projects phrase you need several value object classes.
Lombok is because of readbility and usability not an option in my case.